# Can I link a .blend file instead of separate object?

Tags: linked-data

If I link objects separate, I have to link all new objects one by one if I change the original file, isn't it?

if I want to link a file which has 3 objects, I have to link 3 objects separately, I can't just link the .blend file, isn't it? But if I add another 5 objects in the external .blend file, I have to link those 5 objects one by one into the .blend I'm working in, they won't be added in the .blend I'm working in automatically, because I didn't link them before. Is there any way to let them be added automatically?

Answer (score 0):

No, as their name tells you: links are... A link between two files. You make a link between something in an external .blend and the .blend you're working in.
No matter what you have linked, it will update once the changes are saved in the linked file and the link reloaded (or the entire working blend reloaded).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But what I mean is, if I want to link a file which has 3 objects, I have to link 3 objects separately, I can't just link the .blend file, isn't it? But if I add another 5 objects in the external .blend file, I have to link those 5 objects one by one into the .blend I'm working in, they won't be added in the .blend I'm working in automatically, because I didn't link them before. Is there any way to let them be added automatically?

Comment: @newbie I suggest adding this information into your question

Answer (score 0):

You can create a collection in the original blend file with all necessary objects.

Link the collection in the link blend.

When you add object to the original blend to the collection, the collection will update in the link blend.

Comment: But if I link a collection, everything will combine together, I can't edit contains in the collection separately, isn't it?

Comment: Yes. Although you can just make the object from the collection local and they will be linked at object level. (You could hide collection and only unhide it to "import" the new objects.)